# Visa services in time of War

Tags: visas, embassies, libyan-citizens

I am from Libya.  Because of war all the embassies have closed in my country.  Would it be possible for me to apply for a visa in a different country?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  If you are in Libya and you are trying to get a visa in some different country you need to get there first and in most cases you need a visa.  So how would you propose to do that?  And where do you want to get a visa to?  Some countries don't allow that if consulate services are available in that country

Comment: @Karlson Neighboring countries allow Libyans to enter without a visa.

Comment: @Karlson That's the whole reason this question is asked, right? ;)

Comment: @MeNoTalk You have to get there first. :)

Answer (score 2):

Independent of the reason, it is quite common that not all countries are represented everywhere with a diplomatic mission. In these cases, consular services are often offered by offices in a neighbouring country or by a third country.

Depending on which country you want to visit, you have to check yourself where to apply for a visa. It is hard to give general advice and a far too broad topic for one question to give you advice an all the roughly 200 countries you may want to visit.

But let's take Norway as an example, since they don't have a regular diplomatic mission in Libya and it was easy to find online information. Libyan citizens intending to visit Norway must apply for short-term visas at the German embassy in Tripoli and for long-term visas at the Norwegian embassy in Algiers. If the German embassy in Tripoli should close (it seems to be open at the moment), I would suppose that the Norwegian embassy in Algiers would be able to help with short-term visas as well.